# Input and out put SNR of Low pass filter

Tags: filter

A low pass filter has L=20mH and C=0.0012F .the input signal amplitude is 2V peak to peak and its frequency is 5k Hz .An unwanted noise input is also prsent with amplitude of 0.2 V peak to peak and a frequency of 50 Hz.Input SNR.output SNR=?

Comment: This is poorly phrased - if it is noise it will not have a single frequency in its spectrum. Better to call it an interferer.

Comment: Also an inductance of 20mH and cap of 0.0012 farads has a low pass frequency of 32 Hz meaning your 5 kHz signal is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a question from a textbook.

This also sounds like you haven't understood the material in the textbook.
Maybe you should study it more and try to find answers to:

- What is SNR ?
- How do I determine SNR ?
- What does a filter do ?
- How does the filter behave for 50 Hz and at 5 kHz signals ?
- What then happens to a signal consisting of a 50 Hz and a 5 kHz component ?
- What will be the amplitudes of these signals at the input and the output of the filter ?